# How does post-humanism deal with Kants Copernican turn?

Tags: kant, postmodernism

Presumably as a term it decentres the human subject as inherited from Renaissance humanism; this continuing the Copernican revolution of decentring the human habitus. This suggests it bypasses Kants Copernican turn - which returned or re-enthoned human subjectivity as the originary point of metaphysics and its associated epistemology. One supposes also its an ancillary project of post-modernity.

How does post-humanism effect this *detour* around Kant or *through* him?